# An admissible heuristic function

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-algorithm

I want an admissible heuristic function to implement A star algorithm to solve this question :

There is a graph ( some nodes and some weighted paths between them ) . 
Each node has some animals and we have to traverse the graph to see all given animals with a minimum distance from start node .

So :

There is a weighted graph and each node has some animals .
We are going to see all given animals ( from input ) with a minimum distance .

What heuristic function do you recommend ?

Comment: Please avoid asking algorithms homework questions here.

Comment: Sounds like the nodes of your A* search tree should not be the nodes of your graph. Instead you can model a state as a combination of the current graph node and the subset of animals already visited. I guess I'd rather use Dijkstra, though, as I can't see an obvious heuristic yet. Even without animals, using A* would usually be based on some embedding of graph nodes into the euclidean plane, so that you can quickly estimate distances. You don't mention any such information as part of your problem description.